# Form not rendering in template

Tags: python, django

A Django form is not rendered in template. Please help me to sort out this problem.

**forms.py**

```py
from django import forms


class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    subject = forms.CharField(required=True)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

my view
**views.py**

```py
def contactform(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
        form = ContactForm()
    return render(request, 'portfolio/contact.html', {'form': form})
```

my templtae
**contact.html**

```
<form action="" method="post">
 {% csrf_token %}
 {{ form.as_p }}
 <input type="submit" value="send">
 </form>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Please update your question with the actual HTML output you get. I mean everything you get inside `<form action="" method="post">`